# How to fetch all data with fetch_assoc while loop while using exit()?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, while-loop

I can't seem to echo all of my data with `assoc` and `exit();`. I looked up other questions similar and found this:

```
if(isset($_POST['postuserid'])){
        $uid = $_POST['postuserid'];



        $ssql = "SELECT * FROM foodid WHERE postid=$uid";
        $rresult = mysqli_query($db,$ssql);
        while ($lrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rresult)){
             if($lrow !== FALSE) {
            echo $lrow['userid'];
            exit();
             }
        }
        }
        }
```

No success. I also tried putting `exit()` outside each bracket and I still get the same result. I only fetch one data at a time. I know that using `exit()` causes this, but is there a way to fetch all data with it?

Comment: For starters: `while ($lrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rresult) !== false){` meaning, it wont loop at all of there are no results.

Comment: There is also the [`fetch_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) method, returns a nice array so you don't have to loop through it. It however is not a generator and is not as efficient memory wise.

Comment: @Xorifelse thank you, but using your first answer actually just gave me no results anyway. Nothing displays.

Comment: If nothing displays, there are no results (using the code in the first comment).

Comment: @Xorifelse What? When I remove it I can see my results. I'm sorry, but I just don't know.

Comment: `while ($lrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rresult) !== false){echo $lrow['userid'];}` will display any result from the query.

Comment: @Xorifelse Yeah it's still now showing. I'm not sure if there's an error in your code or what...

Comment: Just before the loop do a `var_dump($rresult)`.

Comment: Ok, i did the var_dump and not sure what I'm looking at: `object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(2) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(18) ["type"]=> int(0) }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174689/discussion-between-xorifelse-and-laney-williams).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple solutions, I will display the more commonly used methods:

```
$ssql = "SELECT * FROM foodid WHERE postid=$uid"; 
$rresult = mysqli_query($db,$ssql); 
if($rresult){
  $data = mysqli_fetch_all($rresult, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  die(json_encode(mysqli_fetch_all($rresult, MYSQLI_ASSOC)));
} else {
  header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 500 Internal Server Error', true, 500);
  // Do your error logging.
  die();
}
```

Or without the fetch_all incase you want to alter some of the data:

```
$ssql = "SELECT * FROM foodid WHERE postid=$uid"; 
$rresult = mysqli_query($db,$ssql); 
while ($lrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rresult)){ 
  $ret[] = $lrow; 
} 

die(json_encode($ret));
```

### Note:

1. Keep in mind that you wide open to mysql injection attacks, resolved
       if you would be using [prepared
       statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).
2. In the second example I did not diagnose if the query was successful. It is a bad practise not to do so.